# Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element' - Angular Circular Slider

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, circular-slider

I'm trying to use https://github.com/princejwesley/angular-circular-slider
inside my website as a gender slider, it works when I initially load the page with it.

But when I go to another page in the website and then back to the profile, the slider errors out with the error in the title (as seen in the console). The pages use ng-route to load, I would think this is the culprit.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.1"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#postsNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Posts</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="postsNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#/profile">Profile</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view></div>
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here also is a Plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LkzBlHbELK8gHro4XStU

- in the menu, click profile to see the circular slider
- click login to go back
- go to the profile again
- Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Comment: Have you solved this issue / found any alternate solution ? Or still having this issue ?

Comment: I haven't looked at this project in a while so it might take a little time to dig out, but i did solve the problem.

EDIT: at first glance it looks like i made a separate controller for the login page that initializes the slider every time it's loaded